# ASP.NET MVC5 Login based on custom User Table with CustomerId

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I would like to create a login based on my existing User Table.

In my user Table I also have a CustomerId, that I would like to use to filter out results on all other Views so the user may only see results that have the same CustomerId.

I have table LoginDetail:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Insighter.Models
{
    public class LoginDetail
    {
        public int LoginDetailId { get; set; }
        public string LoginEmail { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How to Create a Login based on the LoginEmail and Password, and then how to pass the Customer Id to each Controller to show only related information in each of the Views?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

When they fill in an email and a password, you have to check if this combination (email and password) exists in your database.

If this combination exists: Read the customerId from the database and save the ID in a session. Now, you can use the customerId (in the session) in your Controllers.